# Problem when upgrading Debian from stable (lenny) to testing (squeeze)

Tags: debian, upgrade

I just got a VPS for private use, and wanted to upgrade it to Debian testing (squeeze) in order to have newer packages. The actual version was Debian stable (lenny).

What I did is simply :

1. edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and replace `lenny` with `squeeze`
2. run `apt-get update`
3. run `apt-get dist-upgrade`

This is AFAIK the standard way of upgrading a machine. However, I got the following error :

```
Selecting previously deselected package insserv.
dpkg: considering deconfiguration of sysv-rc, which would be broken by installation of insserv ...
dpkg: yes, will deconfigure sysv-rc (broken by insserv).
(Reading database ... 37095 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking insserv (from .../insserv_1.12.0-14_i386.deb) ...
De-configuring sysv-rc ...
Setting up insserv (1.12.0-14) ...
(Reading database ... 37124 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace sysv-rc 2.86.ds1-61 (using .../sysv-rc_2.87dsf-8_all.deb) ...
touch: setting times of `/etc/init.d/.legacy-bootordering': Bad address
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/sysv-rc_2.87dsf-8_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/sysv-rc_2.87dsf-8_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When trying to install sysv-rc itself, I get the following error. The file in question (`/etc/init.d/.legacy-bootordering`) exists, but is empty.

Has anybody an idea of what causes this error, and how I could solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from a preinst script (a package maintainer script that is run before the installation of the package). It is likely to be '/var/lib/dpkg/info/sysv-rc.preinst'

touch fails to set the modification date of /etc/init.d/.legacy-bootordering.

Try to 'touch' any file yourself. Try to delete it and rerun it.

Did apt upgrade the glibc before sysv-rc ?
There are many bugreport concerning that problem, not only on Debian.

Look for "touch bad address" on search engines...

I believe this is something related to both (kernel + libc)

Comment: Yes, I found out about the "touch bad address" problem later. Looks like we have to wait until the bug is fixed... Thanks for the input though !

Answer (score -1):

The standard upgrade instructions usually include an basic upgrade (`upgrade` or `safe-upgrade`) before the `dist-upgrade` step. You should give the upgrade instructions in the release notes a read. The notes for Sqeeze do not appear to be available yet, unsurprisingly, but those for Lenny should be a good start: http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html

Comment: As I can re-install the VPS to its original state, I tried to first do a dist-upgrade on lenny to have all packages up to date before changing to squeeze. But I get the same error...

Comment: It seems that Debian testing is currently broken, according to a moderator on Debian.net. Let's wait for a few days before trying again.

Comment: `update` doesn't upgrade any packages.

Comment: Sorry, that should have been upgrade - I'll correct the reply.